How to best write a sum of chains
Disclaimer: I know hardly anything about this math topic, I don't even know if what I will describe can be called a "set of chains", I am asking this question precisely to get some advice on how to best explore this topic and solve my problem.
I stumbled upon this topic while studying something else (neural nets).

Consider $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^{N} \to \mathbb{R}^N$ non linear and such that:
$$\sigma \begin{pmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}f(v_1)\\f(v_2)\\\vdots\\f(v_n)\end{pmatrix}$$
where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is also a non linear function. $\sigma$ is defined this way in general, for all $N$, it simply acts on the elements of the whole vector.
Consider now the following sequence of vector equations:
For $B=1$:
$$\vec{y} = W_{21}\vec{x}$$
For $B=2$:
$$\vec{y} = W_{31}\vec{x} + W_{32} \circ \sigma \circ W_{21}\vec{x}$$
For $B=3$:
$$\vec{y} = W_{41}\vec{x} + W_{42} \circ \sigma \circ W_{21}\vec{x} + W_{43} \circ \sigma \circ W_{31}\vec{x} + W_{43} \circ \sigma \circ W_{32} \circ \sigma \circ W_{21}\vec{x}$$
By now you probably see what is going on: we are summing over all the possible chains from $1$ to $B+1$, the chains are "linked" by the non linear function $\sigma$.
My question is: is there a clean, standard way, to deal with this and maybe find a compact general expression for $\vec{y}$ for all $B \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$?
